# Inflated layout inside Binder of RecyclerView is not returning any content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have `RecyclerView` and `ViewHolder` holding items. Each item has list of other items. These are just inflated in for loop to container within `RecyclerView` items.

This inflated `View` is `ViewPager` with custom Adapter. I want to achieve swiping effect inside `Recyclerview` item's children.

But no content is visible.

Is this possible to do inside `RecyclerView`?

So in general `RecyclerView` item has its children and each children will load its children from API call on swipe.

Update#2: 
ViewPager is working as intended if I add pages to list before adapter initialization, but if I rewrite pages from API call, it will add them but `swipePager.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()` will not refresh `pages` list. List has more than 1 child but I cant swipe because `ViewPagerAdapter` still thinks it has only 1 page.

This would be last thing I need to fix. I've read that `notifyDataSetChanged()` is bugged in ViewPager and it has different behaviour than for `RecyclerViewAdapter`. Anyone has some solution how to refresh adapter?

Custom ViewPager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.my.project.SwipeViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Code inside `onBind` for single `RecyclerView` item:

```
parts.removeAllViews()
val li = LayoutInflater.from(root.context)
j.parts.forEachIndexed { i, p ->
                val v = li.inflate(R.layout.pager_layout, parts, false).apply {
                        val swipePager = findViewById<SwipeViewPager>(R.id.pager)
                        var nextParts = emptyList<PageItem>()
                        val pages = mutableListOf<PageScreen>()
                        var alreadySwiped = false
                        val swipeListener = object : OnSwipeOutListener{
                            override fun onSwipeOutAtEnd(){
                                //call API on swipe
                                if (!alreadySwiped){
                                    getUpcomingData(p.itemId){ list->
                                        alreadySwiped = true
                                        nextParts = list
                                        pages.clear()
                                        nextParts.forEach { np->

                                            pages.add(
                                                    PageScreen(
                                                            a,
                                                            app,
                                                            map,
                                                            np,
                                                            onClick = {
                                                                onItemClicked(np.nextId)
                                                            }
                                                    )
                                            )
                                        }

                                        swipePager.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            override fun onSwipeOutAtStart(){

                            }
                        }

                        //add first item which is known
                        pages.add(PageScreen(
                                a,
                                app,
                                map,
                                p,
                                onClick = {
                                    onItemClicked(p.nextId)
                                }
                        ))

                        swipePager.apply {
                            setOnSwipeOutListener(swipeListener)
                            adapter = SwipePagerAdapter(pages.toList()).also { it.notifyDataSetChanged() }
                        }

                    }


                parts += v
            }
```

Comment: it is possible to have horizontal scroll inside each child of recyclerview. in the first line you are removing all view from parts wut are you adding them back?

Comment: You have to remove and add them again because of recycling. If I dont do it views will not be properly recycled.

Comment: Also I wanted to use inner recyclerview for this, but RecyclerView inside RecyclerView is not a good solution here, because it has horizontal scrolling, but swiping is not working for RecyclerView, you can just scroll views but I need that Swipe effect which ViewPager is providing.

Comment: Also recyclerview's items children will have up to 5 pages so recycling is not needed here in terms of performance.

Comment: swipe should work. one of the primary use case of recycler view is to have child scroll diff than parent one.

Comment: https://medium.com/@manikanta.garikipati/from-viewpager-to-recycler-view-part-1-874be5e6c347
check this if it helps